# Limited calculations in C#

Tags: c#, operators, calculation

I needed advanced calculation for my project in c#. For example, calculating decimal places up to 10 or 12 digits. But the problem is that c# only calculates up to 6 digits.
Or displays very large numbers infinitely. such as multiply to doubles together.
Is there any way to change these restrictions?
Thanks

For example, I want to divide 1 by 3. The result in c# is 0.333333. only 6 decimal digits. but I need something like 0.3333333333 with 10 decimal digits.
This problem even exists in the setting of variables. That is, a decimal number with 10 decimal places in c# becomes a number with 6 decimal places.

Comment: Use `BigInteger` from `System.Numerics`. But how to use for calculating decimal place? this is for you to find out.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us a bit more about the calculation you want to do. C# has many different value types you can use..

Comment: @Aldert: Well what the OP asked for is crystal clear and it cannot be achieved by most built-in types.

Comment: The `Decimal` type in C# uses many more digits than that. You are not displaying it properly.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder But it can be achieved by *some*. It doesn't have to be supported by *most* of the types, it is enough if one of them supports it, and `System.Double` or just `double` supports 10 digits of precision (even more in fact), as does `System.Decimal` or just `decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `decimal` as a type. Use `m` after the number. `1/3m` for example.

Answer (score 0):

A double is in you case enough

```
double myDec;
myDec = 1.0 / 3.0;
Console.WriteLine(myDec);
```

This shows you: 0.333333333333333

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types

decimal goes to 28 digits

Answer (score 0):

You can choose System.Double or System.Decimal for the calculation. Double type supports 17 digits of precision and Decimal suppports 28 digits.

As described on Docs, Decimal is the most precise floating type in .net.

> The Decimal value type is appropriate for financial calculations that
> require large numbers of significant integral and fractional digits
> and no round-off errors. The Decimal type does not eliminate the need
> for rounding. Rather, it minimizes errors due to rounding. For
> example, the following code produces a result of
> 0.9999999999999999999999999999 instead of 1.

Please refer to Docs for details. It can explain it in a splendid way with examples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-5.0